# How can I turn my Symfony 4 application from dev mode into production mode?

Tags: symfony, caching, terminal, server, production-environment

On my local host I am able to turn the environment from development mode into production mode by changing in .env:

```
 APP_ENV=dev
```

into

```
APP_ENV=prod
```

and after this I clear the cache in the terminal:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

This works fine on the local machine. But on my server I am not able to clear the cache with this command.

The terminal outputs the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in www/project/bin/console
```

So on my page I see only:

> Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>   Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
>   error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
>   inconvenience caused.

Comment: Check php version on the prod server. Symfony 4 requires 7.1.3+

Comment: Whats your OS (Linux, Windows)?

Comment: @VadimAshikhman The php version is up to date. I mean the dev mode is working very well on the server. Just not the production mode

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev The system of the server is Linux. My local system is OSX

Comment: Better check the server php version again.  The error message is exactly what you get when trying to run the console using a php version less than 7.1.  I know you said it runs on your server in development mode but that is extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console selecte php version. It can differ to the version of **php-fpm** configured in your **nginx virtual host**. You need at least **7.1**

Check

```
php -v
```

If you have multiple php versions installed, you can change current console php version with this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

I will provide your with a list of possible php versions that currently installed on your server.

Comment: I am not allowed to use "sudo" on the server because it is a shared host

Comment: But you must be able to check php version with php -v

Comment: yes, php -v gives the output PHP 5.6.37 but my website is set to PHP 7.1 and when I called the host, they also told me it is PHP 7.1, they cannot make a higher php version

Comment: php -v shows you actual output. It is 5.6.37 anyway your host told you
You can describe them current situation, if you have no permission to change it without sudo.

Comment: I used php info on my side and there it is written php version 7.1. so this must be true

Comment: So it must be another reason

Comment: Keep in mind that the php version used by your website is not necessarily the same as the one used from the console.  So the support folks might be absolutely correct when they say the site is 7.1.  How exactly are you running php -v?  Did you ssh in?  Because it is a bit unusual to have shell access to a shared server.  In any event, call them back and ask how to adjust the console version of php.  Probably just a question of tweaking your PATH variable.

Comment: Another thing you can try to do which might work depending on how your host is configured as well as permissions is: /usr/bin/php7.1 -v And if that works then /usr/bin/php7.1 bin/console --version should work as well.